# Fill local database(sqlite) with initial data at first time application starts

Tags: c#, sqlite, console-application

**My problem:**

I am working on a console application with a local(sqlite) data base. I have lots of objects that should be loaded in the database on first time start up. I have it working but the problem is that I need to hardcode all those objects in my application inside classes, initialize them and then fill the database. For me it seems messy to have arround 25+ objects hardcoded in my application.

I am thinking of making a special assembly just to initialize the database. but I still would have all those objects hardcoded in my application.

**My questions**

1. Is making a seperate assembly a good way to organize the application, and if not 
   how can I avoid having those 25+ objects hardcoded in my application?
2. Is there a better way to store those objects instead of inside classes?

Comment: You can create a separate assembly for them, if you like. But you can also keep them in the same project, I don't see anything wrong in that. Put all the classes in one folder. I don't know why you call that "hardcoded", they're not hardcoded, you're loading them from the database. If you move them to another assembly, the code will be identical except in a separate project instead of a subfolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you should use a JSON file. You code all the data inside this file in a format which matches the ones of the models, so on startup your program can easily parse the file and it can creates the objects that you need without hardcoding anything. The JSON format is the ideal because it's easy to compile by hand and easy to read by code.